# How to save only the new rows AND modified rows in datagridview?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm trying to save my data from datagridview row to my sql database. My problem is with my current code, it reads and updates all the rows regardless if it has any changes or not. I know this is going to be a problem especially if my table has large amounts of data.

These are what I did with my code so far:

```
//retrieve data from dbase
public void loadToDGV()
   {
       DBConn.DBConnect();
       SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from TableName", DBConnection.conn);
       sqlDA.Fill(dataTable);
       gridView.DataSource = dataTable;
   }
```

Below is what's in my Save button.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gridView.Rows)
{ 
     DBConn.DBConnect();
     SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
     comm.Connection = DBConnection.conn;
     comm = new SqlCommand("SPName", DBConnection.conn);
     comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

     comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells["ID"].Value == DBNull.Value ? "" : row.Cells["ID"].Value);
     comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I have another sample code where I can only save modified rows

```
changeTable = dataTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
foreach (DataRow row in changeTable.Rows)
{ 
     DBConn.DBConnect();
     SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
     comm.Connection = DBConnection.conn;
     comm = new SqlCommand("SPName", DBConnection.conn);
     comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

     comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row["ID"].ToString());
     comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

What I wanted to do is save only **BOTH** the "New Rows" **AND** "Modified Rows".
Is there any way to only get newly added/edited rows? and not include all the rows from the gridview?

My Stored Procedure only checks if the ID is existing or not.

*IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE WHERE ID = @ID)
-- INSERT QUERY*

*ELSE
-- UPDATE QUERY*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using a loop at all, nor even referring to the grid. You obviously have a `DataTable` already. If you're not already doing so, populate it with a data adapter, bind it to a `BindingSource` and bind that to the grid. When it's time to save, call `EndEdit` on the `BindingSource` call `Update` on the data adapter and pass the `DataTable`. That's it, that's all. There's no need to call `GetChanges`.

Obviously you will have to configure the data adapter appropriately, with an `InsertCommand` to insert new records and an `UpdateCommand` to save modified records. I won't go into specifics as you haven't gone into specifics but there are plenty of examples around. You can find my own [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872).

EDIT:

The short answer to your question is that, if you want both modified and added rows, then specify both `Modified` and `Added` rows. The `DataRowState` enumeration has the `Flags` attribute, which means that you can create compound values. That would mean that this:

```cs
changeTable = dataTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
```

would become this:

```cs
changeTable = dataTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.ModifiedData Or RowState.Added);
```

If you were going to then loop through those rows, you wouldn't create a new command object every iteration. You'd create one command and add the parameters once, then simply set the `Value` of each parameter in the loop. You would also need to call `AcceptChanges` on the original `DataTable` afterwards.

You should do any of that though. As I said, you should use the same data adapter as you used to retrieve the data to save the changes. Normally you'd use different SQL for the `InsertCommand` and `UpdateCommand` but, in your case, you can use the same. Just create a single command object with the appropriate parameters and assign it to both the `InsertCommand` and `UpdateCommand` properties, then call `Update`.

Comment: sorry for not going into specifics. I edited my question and added more details to my code. There's a bit of a learning curve for me as I only self-study here and on youtube so your help is much appreciated

Comment: I have added more detail to my answer.

Comment: @Star, there's no need to call `AcceptChanges` if you call `Update` on a data adapter. It will make the call automatically, unless you explicitly set `AcceptChangesOnUpdate` to `false`.